# Sinatra/1.4.3 use Rack::Session::Cookie warning

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra

my configuration code

```
require 'sinatra'

#set :environment, :production
enable :sessions
enable :logging
set run: true

case
  when production?
    set port: 8081
  when development?
    require 'sinatra/reloader'
    require 'better_errors'
    use BetterErrors::Middleware
    BetterErrors.application_root = __dir__
end

use Rack::Session::Cookie, key: 'N&wedhSDF',
    domain: "localhost",
    path: '/',
    expire_after: 14400,
    secret: '*&(^B234'

get '/' do
  erb :hello
end
```

It still shows a warning:

```
SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.
```

but it doesn't show up on production

the question is, why does it still show the warning even if the Rack::Session::Cookie already set?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are using both

```
enable :sessions
```

which [makes Sinatra setup cookie based sessions](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1701), and

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, ...
```

which also adds sessions to your app, so you end up with *two* instances of `Rack::Session::Cookie` in your middleware stack.

The warning is being generated by the session middleware included by Sinatra. By default Sinatra [doesn’t create a session secret when running in the development environment](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1899) (in classic mode at least, it does for modular apps), and so Rack generates the warning in development.

You should only need one of the two ways of enabling sessions, using two together could result in them interacting in unexpected ways.

To avoid the warning, you can explicitly set a secret for the Sinatra session with the `session_secret` option:

```
enable :sessions
set :session_secret, '*&(^B234'
```

You can also pass the options hash as an argument when enabling sessions. Instead of `enable :sessions`, do this:

```
set :sessions, key: 'N&wedhSDF',
  domain: "localhost",
  path: '/',
  expire_after: 14400,
  secret: '*&(^B234'
```

Comment: Can you explain what setting the ``session_secret`` does? I've been looking for an answer but I can't find it anywhere. My best guess is that it uses it as a salt for the hash so that people can't forge cookies.

Comment: @Piccolo Yes, it is to prevent people forging cookies, but it is used as the key in a [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) rather than as a salt. Check out the [Rack cookie session code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.4/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb) for more info.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm looking into it right now. Also, is there any reason why I can't generate a new secret key at the start of my application?

Comment: @Piccolo, I'm pretty sure the consequences of that, would be that every time you restart your app, sessions would be destroyed, so people would have to log back in... among other things you might be storing in sessions.

Comment: My issue is all about using both ways to enable sessions. Thanks for figuring it out!